# How can I find out when new English Dubbed One Piece episodes will be released?

Tags: one-piece

I know there are currently over 700 One Piece episodes with subtitles, lots of people like the subtitles, I strongly prefer the English dubbed version. The English dub currently ends at 421 sadly.

How can I find out when new English dubbed episodes will be released?

Comment: By the way guys, if you're viewing this you might find it interesting that, looking back on this question asked three months ago, I've already watched all of the remaining episodes in subtitled form, and ***it will no longer bother you after watching 100 subtitled episodes.*** This is partly because I enjoyed the story so much.

Comment: Very true. Subtitled is kind of hard to get used to, but its well worth it since almost if not all anime is Subbed long before its dubbed, many of the more obscure but very good ones are never dubbed, and though it takes a while, once you get used to it, the impact to the experience is minimal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can keep a track of the dubbed episode DVD releases on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_One_Piece_episodes#Season_13_.282009.E2.80.932010.29) where you can see that the dubbed versions of Episode 422-433 will be released on December 15, 2015 and the dubbed versions of episode 434-445 will be released on January 26, 2016.

**The dubbed version is released online 2 weeks before the DVD Sales go out.** You can find them uploaded on [Funimation site](http://www.funimation.com/shows/one-piece/videos/episodes) or other sites.

You may also keep track of the DVD release dates on [One Piece Wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/FUNimation_Entertainment/Episode_List_and_DVD_Releases) where too, you shall find the same information.

A final alternative is [this](http://www.english-dubbed.com/knowledge-bazaar/releases/) site which is not only for tracking the release of the dubbed episodes of One Piece but also other anime.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in streaming episodes, Funimation has a schedule up at this website address: http://www.funimation.com/schedule